# Tests React component with jest and enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

i have components presented below. I am totally new in unit testing. Can anyone give any one give me advice how and what should I test in this component? I was trying to shallow render it, to check is text in h2 is present but i still getting errors.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Form, Field } from 'react-final-form';
import { useHistory, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { loginUser, clearErrorMessage } from '../../redux/auth/authActions';
import Input from '../Input/Input';
import ROUTES from '../../routes/routes';
import './LoginForm.scss';

const LoginForm = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  const { loading, isLogged, errorMessage } = useSelector(state => state.auth);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLogged) {
      history.push('/');
    }

    return () => {
      dispatch(clearErrorMessage());
    };
  }, [dispatch, history, isLogged]);

  const handleSubmitLoginForm = values => {
    if (!loading) {
      dispatch(loginUser(values));
    }
  };

  const validate = ({ password }) => {
    const errors = {};

    if (!password) {
      errors.password = 'Enter password!';
    }

    return errors;
  };

  return (
    <article className="login-form-wrapper">
      <h2>SIGN IN</h2>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmitLoginForm} validate={validate}>
        {({ handleSubmit }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} autoComplete="off" className="login-form">
            <div className="login-form__field">
              <Field name="email" component={Input} type="email" label="E-mail" />
            </div>
            <div className="login-form__buttons">
              <button type="submit" className={loading ? 'button-disabled' : ''}>
                Sign in
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        )}
      </Form>
    </article>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

I am open for any advices :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am not recommending using `shallow` in your tests and [here](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/why-i-never-use-shallow-rendering) is a great article why.

I also recommend to check out [react-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library) instead of Enzyme as it is much nicer to use.

Now, to answer your question. You are using here hooks for `redux` and `react-router`, so you need to provide the necessary data to your componenent in test so that it can use those hooks. Let me show you an example test (that checks text in `h2` element):

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {MemoryRouter, Route} from 'react-router';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';

describe('Login Form', () => {
  it('should have SIGN IN header', () => {
    const store = createStore();
    const component = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/login']}>
          <Route path="/:botId" component={LoginForm} />
        </MemoryRouter>
      </Provider>
    )

    expect(component.find('h2').text()).toEqual('SIGN IN');
  });
});
```

Some explanation to this example.

- I am using `mount` instead of `shallow` as I prefer to render as much as possible in my test, so that I can check if everything works together as it should.
- You can see that I am not rendering my component directly, but rather it is wrapped with other components (`Provider` from `react-redux` and `MemoryRouter` from `react-router`). Why? Because I need to provide **context** to my Component. In this case it's `redux` and `router` context so that the data used inside exists and can be found (for example `useSelector(state => state.auth)` must have some state provided so that it can access `auth` property). If you remove any of them you would get some error saying that this context is missing - go ahead and check for yourself :).
- See [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/testing) for some details around testing with `router` context
- As for testing with `redux` in my example there is a `createStore` function that I didn't define as there are a few approaches to this. One involves creating a real store that you use in your production application. This is the one that I prefer and colleague of mine wrote great article around this topic [here](https://blog.pragmatists.com/genuine-guide-to-testing-react-redux-applications-6f3265c11f63). Other is to create some kind of mock store, like in [this article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-connected-component-test). Again, I prefer the first approach, but whichever is better for you.

Answering your other question on what should you test in this example. There are multiple possibilities. It all depends mostly on you business case, but examples that I would test here includes:

- Typing something into an input, clicking a button and observing that login is successful (by redirecting to new path - `/` in this case)
- not typing a password and clicking a button - error should be shown
- Checking if button class changes when it's loading
- Do not dispatch login action twice, when already loading

And so on...

That's really just a tip of an iceberg on what could be written around testing, but I hope it helps and gives you a nice start to dig deeper into the topic.

Comment: You should be careful about reading an article and believing it. I do not agree with that article tbh.

Comment: Which article do you mean? About shallow rendering? If so, it's not just an article - I have been using shallow for a long time, but the amount of problems that came from it was enormous (especially in case of refactoring, which become impossible after a while) so I just stopped using it and everything become much simpler. I agree there might be different approaches to testing, but that's what works for me and `shallow` blocks my possiblity of free refactoring, without needing to worry about breaking tests.